# Publish/subscription issue with Meteor 1.2.0.1

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe

In a Meteor app, data published to a collection on the server is not appearing in the client.

Starting with a default Meteor application, I have changed the default JavaScript file to the following:

```
Test = new Mongo.Collection("test")

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe("test")
  console.log(Test.find({}).fetch())
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.publish("test", function () {
      var cursor = Test.find({})
      var result = cursor.fetch()
      console.log(result)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
      return cursor
    })

    var selector = {}
    var modifier = { key: "value" }
    var options = {}
    var callback = function (error, data) {
      console.log("Test", error, data)
    }
    Test.upsert( selector, modifier, options, callback )
  });
}
```

In the server Terminal, I can see that a document has been added to the Test collection, and that the collection now contains a document, but the output of `console.log(Test.find({}).fetch())` in the browser is `[]`.

Here's typical output from the server:

```
I20150924-14:38:59.313(-4)? Test null { numberAffected: 1 }
=> Meteor server restarted
I20150924-14:38:59.404(-4)? [ { _id: 'e3B6js9xq3pbspego', key: 'value' } ]
I20150924-14:38:59.405(-4)? [{"_id":"e3B6js9xq3pbspego","key":"value"}]
```

And from the browser:

```
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/
[]                   mongoTest.js:5
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you just do a `console.log(Test.find({}).fetch());` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(Test.find({}).fetch()));` before returning the results of publish?

```
Meteor.publish("test", function () {
      return Test.find()
    })
```

Comment: @Abhay — I've done that, and updated my question. There is definitely a document in the collection on the server.

Comment: Can you try to include the client logic in the start-up block `Meteor.startup(function () { \\insert client here }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected because `subscribe` does not block execution of the browser. After the subscription starts, `Test.find()` executes before the documents will arrive on the client. Here's an implementation that should print the result:

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('test', function() {
    console.log(Test.find({}).fetch());
  });
}
```

A more robust solution would be to use an `autorun`, as it avoids any race conditions with adding the first document:

```js
var handle = Meteor.subscribe('test');

Tracker.autorun(function() {
  if (handle.ready())
    console.log(Test.find({}).fetch());
});
```

Recommended reading: The "subscriptions don't block" section of [common mistakes](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Tracker.autorun(...)` to the client-side code solves the problem:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Tracker.autorun(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe("test")
    console.log(Test.find({}).fetch())
  })
}
```

Output in the browser console is now:

```
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/
[]                   mongoTest.js:6
v [Object]           mongoTest.js:6
  > 0: Object
      _id: "e3B6js9xq3pbspego"
      key: "value"
    length: 1
  > __proto__: Array[0]
```

Apparently `Test.find({}).fetch()` finds an empty collection when the client first connects to the server, and then the server has time to update the collection on the client.